# Error in importing terraform resource for fusionauth

Tags: terraform, fusionauth

I am trying to import an existing fusion-auth api key

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gpsinsight/fusionauth/latest/docs/resources/api_key

I am using below command:

```
terraform import module.fusionauth.fusionauth_api_key.internal_services 'id'
```

Getting error :

```
│ Error: readAPIKey errors: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

How to resolve this
I have used quotes also

Comment: I think fusionauth provider does not support `import` at this time. There is no official 
 documentation for importing any resources.

Comment: i am able to import other resources but not this one

Comment: I would suggest to report an issue with the provider https://github.com/gpsinsight/terraform-provider-fusionauth/issues

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand the question, but if you have the "fusionauth" provider, you shouldn't import anything else.

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    fusionauth = {
      source = "gpsinsight/fusionauth"
      version = "0.1.47"
    }
  }
}

provider "fusionauth" {
  # Configuration options
}
```

It should be something like that.I hope I've helped.